# How to use a Power BI data model across different folders of similar data

Tags: csv, powerbi, data-modeling

I have a system that produces CSV data on a regular event-driven basis (say, daily).  Each event triggers the creation of a new folder and a fixed set of CSV files, each representing different types of data.  For instance:

- PlansDB.csv - data for plans of action
- StepsDB.csv - descriptions of steps used by different plans
- GroupsDB.csv - data on groups that can handle plans
- RoomsDB.csv - data on places where a group can work on a plan
- ResultsDB.csv - the records of results from steps of a plan

These have fields that identify the relationships between the different files, and I have no problems creating a data model for the CSVs in any given folder.

But how do I switch between folders?  Once I have a working data model and some reports built off it, I'd like to view those reports on specific folders of data.  How does that work?  Can I switch easily to yesterday's folder, or last weeks, etc. with minimal effort (preferably just pointing to the folder).

The CSV files maintain the same names across folders which represent the types of the data they store.  Can Power BI use that?

And can I run reports over multiple folders maintaining this data model?  I know of the Folder merge capability, but my attempts at using it just merges all files as if they were the same type, whereas I would need each type merged separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the data source. To do this, from "Edit Queries" select "Data source settings":

[image]

Then click "Change Source..." button and select the new folder. After that Power BI Desktop will tell you to apply the changes and will reload the data from the new folder:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. This appears to require me to change the source settings for every CSV individually. I was really hoping to just point my report to a new folder in one step as my data model is more complex than the example in my question and there are many different CSVs with elaborate relationships. It will be error prone to have to change all types one by one. I've done some searching but can't seem to figure out how to change the folder all at once.